# What's the proper height above a subfloor, for an exterior inswing door threshold? Carpet? Tile? Hardwood?

Tags: doors, subfloor, carpentry

I need to build a custom door threshold for an in-swing exterior door where there's no exterior overhang or porch.

At the moment there is only subfloor, no finish floor.

How high above the subfloor should this threshold be, to accommodate a free swinging door with room for future tile, hardwood or carpet?  Are there guidelines?  If height is a problem, what are the best methods to get weatherstripping sweep without using a lot of door height?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at exterior door thresholds today! You can get them in either 5/8", 3/4", or 1" heights. If the door is already hung, then you choose the height that works best with your current flooring.

In my case, the door and threshold are the same level. I plan to cut the door in order to accommodate a new higher threshold/wstrip. It seems lowest to install it on the threshold. On the door would require it to swing freely until it closes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a code.  I'd do an inch above subfloor just to be safe your door clears carpet or whatever flooring you put down.  However if you have a really unlevel floor you will need to factor that in as well.  Check the height of the sub floor anywhere the door swings.  It might be perfectly fine closed but when you swing that door open it could hit your floor and not open fully if you have an unlevel floor.